# Where can I find Blue, the C# compiler written in C#?

Tags: c#, sample

I was searching for some time today today and yesterday, wherever I could on the internet, to find Blue, the open source C# compiler written in C#, written by Mike Stall. It is an old project, and the link for it on its article, is either broken, or inaccessible to me.
I want it as a sample to learn more about compilers. I thought than this might be a good start.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download and use build_all.bat](https://github.com/steshaw/blue/archive/master.zip)

Not really recommended unless you're gonna use `.NET 1.0 / 1.1`

> It tagets the V1.0/v1.1 runtimes. The current version does not yet support v2.0 (and is actually very confused when it tries to import generics in v2.0 mscorlib)

[Source](https://github.com/steshaw/blue#readme)